# AngularJS: mirror Wordpress permalink settings

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, routes

I'm posting on SO cause my issue is about AngularJS, not Wordpress.
I'm building a single page app using AngularJS (1.6.4) and the WP REST API. Everything fine, but i'm now looking for a solution to mirror the permalink settings for posts.

I thought to extend the rest api to expose them, then inject the `$http` service into my module's `config`

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {       
    $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: partials.folder + 'home.php', controller: 'allposts'});

    var tags = [
        '%year%',
        '%monthnum%',
        '%day%',
        '%hour%',
        '%minute%',
        '%second%',
        '%post_id%',
        '%postname%',
        '%category%',
        '%author%'
    ];
    var urlvars = '';
    var inj = angular.injector(['ng']);
    var $http = inj.get("$http");
    $http.get('wp-json/permalink_api/v0/settings').then(function (res) {
        var settings = res.data;
        var permalink_settings = settings.permalink_settings;

        //This array contains the permalink settings
        var arr = settings.permalink_settings.permalink_structure.split('/');

        //I'll now generate a string using that array...
        for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == "") {
                arr.splice(i,1);
                i=i-1;
            } else {
                if ((ix = tags.indexOf(arr[i]))> -1) {
                    var cleantag = ":" + tags[ix].replace(/%/g, "");
                    urlvars += '/' + cleantag;
                } else {
                    urlvars += '/' +arr[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }).then(function () {
        //...and create a route based on permalink setting
        $routeProvider.when(urlvars, {templateUrl: partials.folder + 'post.html', controller: 'singlepost'});           
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
```

This code is fine once the app is fully loaded, but suffers the fact that the `$http` service is not yet ready in this phase. What happens is that it loads the whole app, then begins applying this config, meaning that json data are loaded too late. The worst consequence is that i can't access the routes directly from browser bar, but only through app's links.

I suppose using interceptors won't change this. Mirror the permalink structure is good for SEO, so i want to achieve this even if i'm creating a SPA, to not mention that it gives full control to the user as with a classic theme.

Any mean to achieve this? Thank you.

**EDIT**
.htaccess settings are well set up; defining any route statically works in any situation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by Wordpress function: it prints a  tag which contains my config.

```
function pre_configure_angular () {
?>
<script>
    angular.module('single-page').config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        var tags = [
            '%year%',
            '%monthnum%',
            '%day%',
            '%hour%',
            '%minute%',
            '%second%',
            '%post_id%',
            '%postname%',
            '%category%',
            '%author%'
        ];
        var urlvars = '';

        var permalink_structure = '<?php echo get_option('permalink_structure'); ?>';

        var arr = permalink_structure.split('/');
        for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == "") {
                arr.splice(i,1);
                i=i-1;
            } else {
                if ((ix = tags.indexOf(arr[i]))> -1) {
                    var cleantag = ":" + tags[ix].replace(/%/g, "");
                    urlvars += '/' + cleantag;
                } else {
                    urlvars += '/' +arr[i];
                }
            }
        }

        $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: partials.folder + 'home.php', controller: 'allposts'});
        $routeProvider.when(urlvars, {templateUrl: partials.folder + 'post.html', controller: 'singlepost'});
        $routeProvider.when('/:page', {templateUrl: partials.folder + 'page.html', controller: ''});

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
</script>
<?php
}
add_action ('wp_head', 'pre_configure_angular');
```

This allowed me to avoid another http request to server as well.